# Update column based on value in another table without joins

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Up front, I'm in a DB class and could use a hint to get closer to the correct answer.

In the `ticket_old` table there is the first and last name of technicians. Only two unique names.

In the new `ticket` table, I've got a `tech_id` column which needs the `int` matching the `last_name` of the tech found in the `ticket_old` table.

I've been trying to do this using the code below, which executes successfully and updates 0 rows.

```
UPDATE ticket,ticket_old
  SET tech_id = (CASE WHEN ticket_old.techLast = 'name1' THEN 1
    WHEN ticket_old.techLast = 'name2' THEN 2
    END)
;
```

-edit, I also tried the following which runs and updates 0 rows.

```
UPDATE ticket,
 (SELECT techLast FROM ticket_old WHERE techLast = 'name1') as src
SET ticket.tech_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

When Comparing two values,
Always use **Double Equal** marks:

SET tech_id = (CASE WHEN ticket_old.techLast == 'name1' THEN 1
WHEN ticket_old.techLast == 'name2' THEN 2
END)

I'm not sure if it is 'name' or "name". Try it.

Comment: I get the error `#1064` near '== 'name1' THEN 1 WHEN